# Calculate Column Using Data from Another Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables: Products and Settings.

Products:

```
Name  BuyPrice SellPrice
======================== 
Coke  15.00    0
```

Settings

```
sellPricePercent
================= 
50
```

I want to set the `SellPrice` from table `Products` value by using `sellPricePercent` from table `settings`. So the result would be:

```
Name  BuyPrice SellPrice
======================== 
Coke  15.00    30
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Not sure how you get 30 from 15 and 50 to begin with but you would either need to join or subselect to do the same thing in a query

Comment: Do you want to update the Products table?

Comment: @AcatnamedMidnight Yes I do actually I was just about to comment on the answer below. Can you help me?

Comment: @Odie, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
update Products, Settings 
set Products.SellPrice = Products.BuyPrice*(100/Settings.sellPricePercent);
```

If you would ever have different sellPricePercent for different products, you could join the tables on product name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select  with cartesian products for the table

```
 select a.Name,  a.BuyPrice, a.buyprice*(100/b.sellPricePercent)
 from Products as a, Settings as b
```

or use a select  column

```
  select Name,  BuyPrice, buyprice*(100/select(sellPricePercent 
                                                       from Settings ))
 from Products
```